# LiveData object is doing the DB callback with the wrong argument value (ignores updated value)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a LiveData object **(_tracklist)**  that is making a call to the Dao and retrieves tracks by the songId argument from RoomDB and store it in the List. The new track with the new songID is inserted to the database successfully and the LiveData observer is triggered in the fragment, but the database call is always with the initial argument value even if the value changes in runtime (songId). How can I trigger the call with the updated value?

The methods run in the following order:
createNewSong(),
recordTrack()

```
private var songID:Long = 0

private val _trackList: LiveData<List<Track>> = db.trackDao().getTracksBySongId(songID) 
val trackList: LiveData<List<Track>>
    get() = _trackList

suspend fun createNewSong(){
        val newSong = Song(0, null, true, "Song ${songList.value?.size?.plus(1)}")
        val job = viewModelScope.async() {
            db.songDao().insert(newSong)
        }
        songID = job.await() //The song ID is changed here
    }


fun recordTrack(name: String, pcmDir: String, wavDir: String) {
        val newTrack = Track(
            0,
            true,
            name,
            pcmDir,
            wavDir,
            TypeConverter.dateToTimestamp(Date()),
            null,
            null,
            songID,
            ""
        )
        
        AudioController.lastRecorded = newTrack
        viewModelScope.launch {
            insertTrackToDb(newTrack)
        }
    }

interface TrackDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE songID = :id")
    fun getTracksBySongId(id:Long):LiveData<List<Track>>
}


//OBSERVER
val trackListObserver = Observer<List<Track>> {
            adapter.submitList(viewModel.trackList.value)
           }
        viewModel.trackList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, trackListObserver)
```

Basically I need to call

```
private val _trackList: LiveData<List<Track>> = db.trackDao().getTracksBySongId(songID)
```

each time when the argument songID is changed and new Track with the new songID value is inserted to the database.

Comment: Can you share what your `trackDao` looks like? Also, I don't think I fully understand the question; Are you trying to change `songID:Long ` and expecting the `LiveData` property to broadcast changes?

Comment: _trackList: LiveData<List<Track>> should receive the Track object with the value of songID each time the Track is inserted to the database. In the example initial value of songID is 0, I run createSong() method for the first time and songID is changed to 1.
After that I run recordTrack() and the new Track object is inserted to the database with the songID = 1, but my livedata is still using the initial value (0) for songID and not receiving the object. If I set initial songID = 1, livedata always receives Tracks with the songID = 1, even if I change it in the runtime. @4gus71n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by using **Transformations.switchMap**

```
private var songID: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData(0)
    private var _trackList: LiveData<List<Track>> = Transformations.switchMap(songID)
    { id ->
        db.trackDao().getTracksBySongId(id)
    }
```